# Intersection of Maximal Ideals of a Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I have to show J(I) is an ideal of R given that J(I) is the intersection of all maximal ideals of R. J is a subset of R containing I. I is an ideal of R.

So far I have,
Let M,N be maximals ideals of R, then M intersected with N is in J(I). If m is an element of the intersection of M and N, then m is in N. Similarly, if n is an element of the intersection of M and N, then n is in M.

Consequently, with a and b elements of R, we have Ma+Nb an element of J(I) for all m in M and n in N. Hence, we can do similar process for all maximals ideals and by the above reasoning, J(I) is closed under addition.

I know I have to prove there's an identity and an inverse in J(I) which I am having trouble with.

Lastly, show that J(I) is an actual ideal of R.

I am still grasping the ideal of ideals, so I am not sure. Any suggestions and hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: $J(I)$ is the intersection of all maximal ideals of $R$"  Do you mean it's the intersection of maximal ideals containing $I$? The intersection of all maximal ideals might not contain *any* nonzero ideal, in some cases.

Comment: The intersection of any family of ideals is another ideal. It has nothing to do with what they contain or if they are maximal. And such an intersection need not contain any invertible elements.

Comment: Ok, I think I see "identity and inverses" probably refers to additive ones, not multiplicative. This is one reason you need to be clear. Disregard my last comment then.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by definition.

To see it's closed under addition, you only need to take $a,b\in J(I)$, then $a,b$ are both in every maximal ideal of $R$ containing $I$, and in each one you already have that $a+b$ is also in them. (1)

For the identity, let's take the ring $(R,+,\cdot)$, and let's call the identity of $R$, $0$ and the additive inverse of $x$, $-x$.

Then since a ring is just an abelian group with extra things, you need to prove that the intersection of these ideals is a subgroup of $(R,+)$ first.

So it's not enough to prove that there is an identity, you must prove that the identity of $J(I)$ is $0$. But this makes things easy too, so now you know the candidate of identity. Similarly, you must prove that for every $x\in J(I)$, the element $-x$ is also in $J(I)$. So it's a subgroup.

Then you must take $r\in R$, and $j\in J(I)$, and see that $rj,jr\in J(I)$. Since $j$ is in every maximal ideal containing $I$, you can repeat the argument in 1 to get the result.

You can see that you don't need to use the fact that $J(I)$ is an intersection of **maximal** ideals. So in this way you can also prove that **any** intersection of ideals is an ideal. But this is a special ideal, if $R$ is commutative it's called the Jacobson Radical of $I$.

Comment: Thank you so much for such detailed help!